# Angularjs jqlite append() and jquery append() act differently with <td>

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to append some  elements to a  and I'm seeing some different behavior when using the built-in jqlite vs using jquery.  I created a fiddle to demonstrate the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/waylon999/5fyBt/1/

It appears as when I do:

```
element.append('<td>Val 1</td><td>Val 2</td>'); // jqlite
```

the  tags are stripped before the string is inserted. But when I try

```
$(element).append('<td>Val 1</td><td>Val 2</td>');
```

It works as I would expect, where the entire string arg in append is appended to the  tag.  I tried a couple of things including

```
angular.element(element).append(....)
```

but I can't find a way to make it work.  Is there something I'm not understanding about how this should work?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery anyway, you could just make sure it's included first and avoid the issue altogether. :)

Comment: Yeah, the 'powers that be' want to avoid adding the full jquery library if possible. I just want to see if I found a good reason to just add it. :)

Comment: if you just want to replace all the contents just use element.html() and it will work

Comment: @user417918 at least the powers at be are cool enough to want to use Angular. and I'd generally agree about not using jQuery if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best I can tell, it's a bug in JQLite:

```
function JQLite(element) {

    ...

    if (isString(element)) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        // Read about the NoScope elements here:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(VS.85).aspx
        div.innerHTML = '<div>&#160;</div>' + element; // IE insanity to make NoScope elements work!
        div.removeChild(div.firstChild); // remove the superfluous div
        JQLiteAddNodes(this, div.childNodes);
        this.remove(); // detach the elements from the temporary DOM div.
    } else {
        JQLiteAddNodes(this, element);
    }
}
```

As you may or may not know, you cannot do this:

```
div.innerHTML = '<div></div><td>asdf</td>';
```

The `td` will be removed.  I'm guessing jQuery doesn't do the same thing (perhaps they're not concerned with NoScope?).  That said, if you want to continue to just use Angular, this works just fine:

```
element[0].innerHTML += '<td>Val 1xx</td><td>Val 2yy</td>';
```

I recommend filing an issue on Angular's github.

Comment: There already is an issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Comment: That appears to be a separate (but similar) issue. Everyone seems to be concerned with fixing things around jqLite, instead of the main jqLite function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this:

```
    var cells = angular.element('<table><tbody><tr>' +
                                '<td>Val 1</td><td>Val 2</td>' +
                                '</tr></tbody></table>').children().children().children();
    element.append(cells);
```

It's ugly there, but I guess you can wrap it in a utility function.

Probably the best solution is to just remove that *IE insanity* line.

http://jsfiddle.net/5fyBt/2/